# %3d instead of = in file path, then i try to open file from resources

Tags: scala, scalatest

I write some tests and to get absolute path from relative path i use this function

```
    private def getAbsolutePath(filePath: String): String = {
        getClass.getResource(filePath).getFile
    }
```

and then i do:

```
println(getAbsolutePath("/parquetIncrementalProcessor/withPartitioning/"))
println(getAbsolutePath("/parquetIncrementalProcessor/withPartitioning/own_loading_id=1/partition_column=test/"))
```

i get:

```
/Users/19658296/csp-fp-snaphot/library/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/parquetIncrementalProcessor/withPartitioning/
/Users/19658296/csp-fp-snaphot/library/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/parquetIncrementalProcessor/withPartitioning/own_loading_id%3d1/partition_column%3dtest/
```

As you can see, instead of =, I get some strange symbol. At the same time, when I try to read these files with a park, he can read the path without %3d, and with %3d he gets the error "Path does not exist".

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(getClass.getResource(filePath).getFile)`

Comment: @Dima it help, can you give it like answer and also write why it's work like that?

Comment: Because `getResource` returns a url, a `=` is invalid in  urls, so it gets encoded. It's all in the documentation, and also, nothing to do with scala really. I don't think, it's worthy of an actual "answer".

Comment: @Dima why not? I would like people to see your answer when they ask a similar question. In addition, when you Google how to get an absolute path to resources, there is nothing said about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like its URL encoded, maybe because using stuff from files and resources are designed to work with Universal Resource Locators. You can `URLDecode` it like so:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder
def getAbsolutePath(filePath: String): String = {
    val path = getClass.getResource(filePath).getFile
    URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8")
}
```